# How can you find row in database using two `WHERE`?

Tags: mysql

The output should be based on the user's name and the status of the user. I tryed to use:

```
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE name='$name', status='$status'";
```

and

```
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE name='$name' AND status='$status'";
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: aside from sql injection, the second query seems fine.

Comment: This is SQL 101, about as basic as you can get. Any tutorial should explain how to do it.

Comment: But I didn't found it.

Answer (score 1):

**status** may be a reserved word. **AND** is the key. I recommend parentheses for clarity. In MySQL (varies in other SQLs) you can use backticks to force keywords and other strange syntax to work. Plus { } helps keep things clean in the PHP side. I assume you are using PHP based on the $ variables.

```
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE (`name`='{$name}') AND (`status`='{$status}'";
```

I am sure others will chime in about better ways to write queries to avoid SQL injection, which is a real issue. But this is the basic syntax.

Comment: It would be better to recommend using statements rather than manually quoting the string literals `$name` and `$status`.